# HTML code strip regexp problem

Tags: javascript, html, regex

In javascript, one of the popular regex is to strip out HTML tags from the text. The code for that is

```
String.prototype.stripHTML = function () { 
             var reTag = /<(?:.|\s)*?>/g; 
             return this.replace(reTag, "");
        };
```

If you try this on `"<b>This would be bold</b>".stripHTML()`, then it outputs as `"This would be bold"`. Shouldn't it output as `""` ?

Doesn't this regex says that match everything which starts with `<` and ends with `>` ? Why didn't this regex start at `<` of `<b>` and end at `>` of `</b>`

Comment: If you use a stripHTML function like that is is acutally a stripTags function like in PHP. So you output is just fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using a [non-greedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy) modifier.

```
(?:.|\s)*?
         ^
```

This causes the match to be the shortest possible, instead of the default which is to match the longest possible match.

```
<b>This would be bold</b>
^-^                  ^--^     Non-greedy: <(?:.|\s)*?>
^-----------------------^     Greedy    : <(?:.|\s)*>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but the `*?` performs an ungreedy match (short match):

```
var reTag = /<(?:.|\s)*?>/g;
```

To perform reedy match (longest match possible), remove the `?`:

```
var reTag = /<(?:.|\s)*>/g;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not a greedy regex, meaning that it matches the *first* `>` it comes across, the `<b>` and `</b>` are separate matches.